# Casting to array type using reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I find myself in a situation where it seems I would need to be able to cast an Object that is an array of some other, non-primitive type, into its concrete array type, to pass to a generic.

The same thing is trivial to get to work with non-array types: `desiredType.cast(o)` yields an object of the correct type.

Would someone be so kind to explain either how to do this with arrays, OR why this would never work?

A demonstration of what I'm attempting to do:

```
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main
{
  public static <T> void testT(T o)
  {
    System.out.println("testT called with " + o + " (" + o.getClass() + ")");
  }

  public static void test(Object o)
  {
    testT(o.getClass().cast(o));
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
  {
    test(new Integer(5));

    Class<?> type = Class.forName("java.lang.Integer");
    Object array = Array.newInstance(type, 2);

    Class<?> arrayType = array.getClass();
    Object[] copy = Arrays.copyOf(arrayType.cast(array), Array.getLength(array)); // NOPE. (casting is optional)

    System.out.println(copy);
  }
}
```

Comment: does anything speak against just casting the array to its actual type, i.e. using `(Integer[]) array`?

Comment: unfortunately not; I'm supposed to be working from a collection of objects (of whom I'd need the generic superclass' first actual type argument).

Comment: collection of objects or array of objects? ;-) If you can, try to omit reflection whenever possible... every time I saw a solution using reflection there were lots of other ideas around that better suited the purpose... but I don't know your use case, so it's just a general recommendation...

Comment: I get them from a collection, typically ArrayList<?>, just wanted to go for a minimal repro.

And reflection might not be the key word; the idea I was trying to capture is that I don't know the type at compile time to do a I(MyConcreteType[]) myMysteryArray cast.

Comment: wait... you transform the `ArrayList` to an array? if so... you need the type already there, otherwise you get a `Object[]`, right?

Comment: Yes. And I get the array from the (Array)List, though the means of doing this  oes not have to be toArray(). `list.toArray(Array.newInstance(elementClass, list.size()))` is giving me grief:  "[...] toArray(T[]) in the type List<capture#-n-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (Object). I'm getting the same in the above repro for Arrays.copyOf().

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187552/discussion-between-roland-and-zyndor).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instead cast it to `Object[]` if you want to keep it dynamic and it will work:

```
Object[] copy = Arrays.copyOf((Object[])arrayType.cast(array), Array.getLength(array));
```

Under the hood it will copy the array as is, i.e. the copy will become an `Integer[]` for your given example.

If it's even more generic what you want to do, you could also check whether a given type is actually an array, before casting, e.g. in your example you could use `arrayType.isArray()` for that.

Comment: Thank you -- the `Object[]` cast (and 'array' type declaration) is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had the question for kotlin jvm (which replaced the `Object` by `Any`). So to cast a generic to an array I used [`typeOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.reflect/type-of.html) from [kotlin-reflect](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html):

```kotlin
private inline fun <reified T> genericReflectionToTypedArray(): T? {
    return java.lang.reflect.Array.newInstance(typeOf<T>().arguments[0].type!!.javaType as Class<*>, 10) as T
}
```

In this case you would know that `T` is an array so, to get the type of the array you would use the `typeOf` and get the java type as class of the first type argument of your `Array<T>`.

The `newInstance` method takes the java type of your Array, and the second parameter is the length of the array.
In this case there are no UNCHECKED CAST.